# Xamarin.Forms Vertical StackLayout in ListView displays only one (first) Child

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    HeightRequest="100">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label
                            Text="{Binding When}"
                            XAlign="Center"/>
                        <StackLayout
                            BackgroundColor="Gray"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding Message}"
                                XAlign="Start"/>
                            <Label
                                Text="{Binding Sender}"
                                XAlign="Start"
                                TextColor="Red"/>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                 </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I am rendering a custom ListView in Xamarin.Forms application. The `StackLayout` which contains two `Label`s (to which "Message" and "Sender" has been bound), currently displays only one child. With the code above, it displays only "Message". If I change code to be

```
<StackLayout
      BackgroundColor="Gray"
      Orientation="Vertical"
      VerticalOptions="Center">
      <Label
         Text="{Binding Sender}"
         XAlign="Start"
         TextColor="Red"/>
      <Label
          Text="{Binding Message}"
          XAlign="Start"/>
  </StackLayout>
```

it displays only sender. In short it is displaying only first child. What have I done wrong here ?

Comment: It appears you are putting the listview inside a Grid, can you try to put the listview outside of the grid?

Comment: It could be also that the second child is not displayed because row height is too small and it is cut off. Try to set RowHeight attribute of ListView.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issue was similar to what @Grisha had pointed out. RowHeight was proving to be lesser, and the second StackLayout was getting clipped.

The solution was to set `HasUnevenRows` property of the `ListView` to be `TRUE`. Thus, `RowHeight` was calculated automatically.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.